# how to use value from a mssql query in a sqlite query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pypyodbc

I have two tables, one in ms sql and other one in sqlite3
I need to update a field in mssql table to the related value from sqlite3 table.

here is my code:

```
import pypyodbc
import sqlite3

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=****'
                              'Database=****;'
                              'uid=****;pwd=****')

cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("select ObjectId, ObjectColumnName,Label from LocalizedLabel "
              "where LanguageId = 1065")

sqlUpdate = ("UPDATE LocalizedLabel "
             "SET Label = ? "
             "WHERE ObjectId = ? and ObjectColumnName = ? and LanguageId = 1065")

cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cursor.fetchall()

srcDB = sqlite3.connect('crmLLDB')

for result in results:
    val = (result[0], result[1])
    print('SELECT "1065" FROM crm '
          'WHERE UPPER(ObjectID)= UPPER(%s) AND ObjectColumnName = %s' % val)
    srcCursor = srcDB.execute('SELECT "1065" FROM crm '
                              'WHERE UPPER(ObjectID)= UPPER(?) AND ObjectColumnName = ?', val)
    if srcCursor.fetchone() is None:
        print("No translation found for " + result[2])
    else:
        translation = srcCursor.fetchone()[0]
        updateVals = (translation, result[0], result[1])
        cursor.execute(sqlUpdate, updateVals)


connection.close()
srcDB.close()
```

objectId is a GuID and other fields are all strings

the print function returns:

```
SELECT "1065" FROM crm WHERE UPPER(ObjectID)= UPPER(b'0340B506-2341-DB11-898A-0007E9E17EBD') AND ObjectColumnName = DisplayName
```

while the watcher gives:

```
result[0] = 'b\\'0340B506-2341-DB11-898A-0007E9E17EBD\\''
result[1] = 'DisplayName'
```

this query of course returns this error:

```
[1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "'0340B506-2341-DB11-898A-0007E9E17EBD'": syntax error)
```

while this query :

```
SELECT "1065" FROM crm WHERE UPPER(ObjectID)= UPPER('0340B506-2341-DB11-898A-0007E9E17EBD') AND ObjectColumnName = 'DisplayName'
```

return the perfect answer,
can someone point out my problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appearaently the problem was with `pypyodbc` and its problem with GuId,
I used `pyodbc` and everything works fine now!

my final code, if some googler in the future passes by:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlite3

startTme = datetime.now()
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=*****;'
                            'Database=****;'
                            'uid=sa;pwd=*****')

cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("select ObjectId, ObjectColumnName,Label from LocalizedLabel "
              "where LanguageId = 1065")

sqlUpdate_p = ("UPDATE LocalizedLabel "
               "SET Label = ? "
               "WHERE ObjectId = ? and ObjectColumnName = ? and LanguageId = 1065")

cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cursor.fetchall()

srcDB = sqlite3.connect('crmLLDB')

jobLength = str(len(results))
i = 0

for result in results:
    val = (result[0], result[1])
    srcCursor = srcDB.execute('SELECT "1065" FROM crm '
                              'WHERE UPPER(ObjectID)= UPPER(?) AND ObjectColumnName = ?', val)
    trans = srcCursor.fetchall()
    for tr in trans:
        updateVals = (tr[0], result[0], result[1])
        cursor.execute(sqlUpdate_p, updateVals)
        i += 1

connection.commit()
connection.close()
srcDB.close()
```